# A differentiable function on $(a,b)$ with nonzero derivative over $(a,b)$ where $f'(c)>0$ for some $c\in(a,b)$ means $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

It certainly seems correct that if you have at least one point $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)>0$, where $f'(x)\ne0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$, then $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$. At least from a calculus standpoint, if $f$ is well-defined (not necessarily continuous), it should be the case that this is true. But how does one show this formally?

The exact statement I am attempting to prove is this:

> Suppose $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function such that $f'(x)\ne0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$. Suppose there exists a point $c\in(a,b)$ with $f'(c)>0$, then $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$.

I thought it might be easiest to prove by contradiction, and then use the intermediate value property to derive a contradiction. Any pointers would be helpful on this one!

EDIT: My original direct proof went something like this:

> Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f'(x)\ne0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$. Take a point $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)>0$. Since $f'(x)\ne0$ for any $x\in(a,b)$ there can be no extreme values on $(a,b)$. Then take some $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(c)=y$ and by the intermediate value property, we are guaranteed that $f'(a)<y<f'(b)$, that is $f$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b)$. Hence $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$.

I'm a little worried about some of the logic in this. It feels incomplete to me.

Comment: This can be proven directly using [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))

Comment: I've added my original proof as an edit. I'm not sure if this is what you had in mind, it feels as though there are some missing elements.

Comment: One problem is that $f$ is defined on $(a,b)$ that is $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ don't make sense.

Comment: You may try to prove it like this. Assume on the contrary that the statement is false. Hence there exists a $x_0\in (a,b)$ such that $f'(x_0)\lt 0$. 
Note that $f'(x_0)\lt 0\lt f'(c)$ and hence by Darboux's theorem $\exists \alpha \in (x_0,c)$ such that $f'(\alpha)=0$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct proof is as follows:

Let $f$ be a differential function on $(a,b)$, with non zero derivative. Let $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)\gt0$. Assume by contradiction that there exist $t\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(t)\lt0$. By Darboux's theorem there exist $s\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(s) = 0$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

According to Darboux's Thereom, if $f$  is a differentiable function in an interval $I$, then the range of its derivative function $f'$ must still be an interval. Using the given condition, we can easily get the conclusion.